# Unity iOS Build Crash : task_set_exception_ports(B07, 400, D03, 0, 0) Error

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, crash

I am trying to build for iOS (Unity 5.1.2, XCode 8.0) and having the crash with the following error

> task_set_exception_ports(B07, 400, D03, 0, 0) failed with error (4 : (os/kern)).

Error occurs on splash screen. In another post, Someone said that It occurs when you try to access deleted pointer. If that's so, then how do I solve this problem in Unity?

Comment: are you using the simulator or actual device? if device, what OS is it running?

Comment: I am using device (iPhone 6, iOS 8.4)

Comment: if you build, then after the crash run the app on the device without xcode, does it still crash? I remember having this same issue, and it turned out to be a problem with unity and iOS 8.4. Updating the device fixed it for me.

Comment: just to be clear, for me, it was only crashing when run from xcode onto the device. running from device was fine.

Comment: I tried running from device. It's still crashing and producing the same error.

Comment: ok, if i was you i would first quickly build an empty project and see if you are still getting the same crash. if you are then you know it's not your game causing it and you should try updating your iphone to ios 9 or 10. If it does not crash then you know it is your game, and possibly update plugins or update unity.

Comment: I tried running empty project on device. It worked fine. There must be something wrong with my project. I updated the plugins and checked too but game still crashed.

Comment: how about updating unity, is that possible or will it break your game?

Comment: I should update Unity and check again. Hopefully that won't break the game.